# How can I control nxt 2.0 robot with a Wiimote in labview?

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, remote-control, labview

I am building a robot with Labview for LEGO Mindstorms and I have wanted to hook up the robot to move based on a Wiimote or Wii remote.  However, I have not found a file to download to enable me to do so.  Does anyone have any *free* files that they have found that come with instructions?  If this is any help I am *only* using lego education sets and my NXT version is a 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

The Wiimote uses 2 forms of communication: Bluetooth 4, and IR for the pointing controls. You'd probably be using bluetooth.

The main problem with the NXT bluetooth is that the NXT is a slave device, not a master device, while the wiimote itself is a slave device as well. For advanced reading on the interfacing methods, the wiibrew community has set up a great page over here: http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote

The next concern is that you *may* have to modify your wiimote a tiny bit for bluetooth data transmission. right now, most of the homebrewers are hard-shorting wires to trigger events.

As far as files for the NXT, I'm afraid that you will likely find little to no files, as the problems stated above are somewhat above what most NXT users are trying to do.

Best of luck on your project!